# How to call Asp.net Core Api action method on every x minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a asp.net api action method. I want to call this method every x minutes. Im using Asp.net core Web api. What is the approach of scheduling this method. Is it through Startup.cs or any other way ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

```cs
public class Startup
    {

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddHostedService<YourBackgroundService>();
        }
    }
```

Then create a custom BackgroundService by inheriting from the `BackgroundService` class:

```cs
    public class YourBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            refreshTimeMs = 1000; //How much delay you want
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //call your function here
                foo();
                await Task.Delay(refreshTimeMs, stoppingToken);
            }
        }

    }
```

[Example in Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks)

Comment: Where do you get the foo() ? Seems like a good example but missing the real implementation example. Can you extend?